# CloudFormation Template equivalent of adding "Access for other AWS accounts"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

So in S3, to allow another account to access objects, you add that account's canonical ID in the following S3 user interface:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to find the CloudFormation Template equivalent for this functionality. However, the docs give no indication of it. The closest I could find about ACLs is [canned ACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-accesscontrol), but these are pre-defined and don't fit my use case.

Does the `AWS::S3::Bucket` resource in CloudFormation have a property for providing "Access to other AWS accounts"?